# Flutter Flappy Search

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, dart-pub

I am struggling to wire up the Flutter Flappy Search Bar to a firebase collection. Spent a couple of days on this now and can't seem to figure it out. Getting the following error in the console:

> VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type
>   'PlatformException' is not a subtype of type 'Error'

I am still learning the ropes so, if anyone could offer me any assistance, it would be most appreciated.

```
class SellHousesPage extends StatelessWidget {

  Database database;
  House house;

  Future<List<House>> getHouses(String name) async {

    List houseList;

    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));

    final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents =
        (await Firestore.instance.collection('houses').getDocuments()).documents;

    houseList = documents.map((documentSnapshot) => documentSnapshot[house.name]).toList();

    return houseList;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          child: SearchBar<House>(
            onSearch: getHouses,
            onItemFound: (House house, int index) {
              return Container(
                color: Colors.indigo,
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(house.name),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```dart
class SellHousesPage extends StatelessWidget {
  Database database;
  House house;

  Future<List<dynamic>> getHouses(String name) async {
    QuerySnapshot response = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('houses')
        .getDocuments();

    return response.documents.map((house) => house).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          child: SearchBar<House>(
            onSearch: getHouses,
            onItemFound: (House house, int index) {
              return Container(
                color: Colors.indigo,
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(house["name"]),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to explain how it works?